# Anything which has internal linkage can be put in header file in C++ . Why?

Tags: c++

eg:- Some below examples. Explanation in every case will be an advantage.

```
1. Static variable/object.
2. Static const variable/object.
3. const variables.
4. inline functions .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `static` at namespace scope means "local to this translation unit", so you'll get a new copy of the object in every unit that includes your header.
2. Same thing.
3. These have internal linkage by default.
4. These don't, but the language has a rule that says you can duplicate these in a program as long as each "copy" looks *exactly* the same. That's because, historically, compilers could only do inlining on functions visible in the same translation unit. Nowadays, link-time optimisation exists.

Comment: static at namespace scope means "local to this translation unit", so you'll get a new copy of the object in every unit that includes your header.

Does that mean static variable of same  name in different files are independent , and can have different values in different files because they have different memory since it is a copy ..